# Ruby on Rails Flash Notice Not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash-message

Flash notice is not working. I am using rails 5.1.
My code is like this:

```
def message
  redirect_to users_path, notice: "Message"
end

<% if flash.present? %>
  <% flash.each do |k, v| %>
    <p class="abc" id="a"><%= v %></p>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <p class="a" id="b"></p>
<% end %>
```

Flash Message is coming few times and few times it's not coming, It's going in else block.

So, for this I have fixed by using flash.keep in users index controller. But Now in every page whenever I am redirecting,that flash message is coming.

Comment: It's hard to guess. Are there any differences in how you achieve both "working" and "not working" situations?

Answer (score 0):

You can try as:

```
def message
  flash[:notice] = 'Message'
  redirect_to users_path
end
```

And in your view:

```
<% if flash[:notice].present? %>
  <% flash.each do |k, v| %>
    <p class="abc" id="a"><%= v %></p>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <p class="a" id="b"></p>
<% end %>
```

Hope it can solve your problem.

Comment: It's not working like that. So, I added falsh.keep in users index action. so now every time flash message is coming but when ever I am redirecting to different page, wherever I don't need that flash message there also I am getting that message.

Answer (score 0):

I think the flash hash is **always** present. You can check if it's empty instead https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-empty-3F

```
<% if flash.empty? %>
  <p class="a" id="b"></p>
<% else %>
  <% flash.each do |k, v| %>
    <p class="abc" id="a"><%= v %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```